# How to align text in notepad++ from left to right margins?

Tags: notepad++

How can I align text to left and right margins by adding extra space between words as necessary?

I'm looking for something like the Justified alignment (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) option in Microsoft Word.

Comment: Are you using columns?

Answer (score -1):

You could try http://codealignment.com/ ([video demo](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9CC5F8C836BD6BDF))

> Code alignment is the practice of formatting your code vertically to improve readability.

```
Shortcuts
Align by... (Dialog)    Ctrl + Shift + =
Align by position... (Dialog)   Ctrl + =, Ctrl + Backspace
Align by Equals     Ctrl + =, Ctrl + =
Align by m_     Ctrl + =, Ctrl + m
Align by "  Ctrl + =, Ctrl + '
Align by .  Ctrl + =, Ctrl + .
Align by Space  Ctrl + =, Ctrl + Space
```